# Does the Facebook 'like' have a limit?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

For some reason, I have a 'like' button to a page in my website that stopped counting at 1,000. Is there any reason? Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Is that page saying `1K Like`, but the actual number is something like 1234?

Comment: I'm using a box_count and it doesn't render 1k. It renders 1000. But for the standard button it shows the 1250 i'm having. Is there any bug related to box or button_count? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook rounds to thousands. You have between 1000 and 2000 fans.

Comment: I'm using a box_count and it doesn't render 1k. It renders 1000. But for the standard button it shows the 1250 i'm having. Is there any bug related to box or button_count? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I know for a fact the limit is not 1000, 10000 or even 100000 because I've seen pages with more likes than that.  It has to be an error with the plugin you are using on your website.  You'd have to post more information about what you are using.

Comment: I'm using a box_count and it doesn't render 1k. It renders 1000. But for the standard button it shows the 1250 i'm having. Is there any bug related to box or button_count? thanks!