# Facebook like button updates the value for every 1,000 'likes'. Can it update on every 'like'?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I guess you realised that, when on a website, you click on the 'like' button -with counter- it normally updates one like by one like in the first ones. Until it reaches 1000 'likes', then it starts updating every 1000 'likes'.

So you could se:

0 likes

1 like

2 likes

..

..

100 likes

..

..

999 likes

1000 likes (then it's not updated onclick until)

2000 likes (then it's not updated onclick until)

3000 likes (then it's not updated onclick until)

...

Is there a way to update the value on every click?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Facebook 'like' have a limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807819/does-the-facebook-like-have-a-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set layout style to standard instead of the box count. But the way box count works is that it displays a rounded number and that isn't currently configurable.  You could log a feature request on their bug tracker tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the exact 'like' count yourself and create a custom counter.

example in PHP

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$facebook_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count,commentsbox_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='{$url}'&format=json"));
echo $facebook_data[0]->total_count;
```

You can see a working example of this on http://askdavid.com