# Why is this Facebook plugin stopping counting 'likes' after 1000?

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Facebook 'like' have a limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807819)
>   [Facebook like button updates the value for every 1,000 'likes'. Can it update on every 'like'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820061)

I have implemented these lines in a master of my site:

```
<div class='txt-espa'><script src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/a ... href =' "+ Request.Url.ToString () +" 'send =' false 'layout = 'button_count' width = '150 'show_faces =' false 'ShowForm =' false 'publish_feed =' false 'font =''></ fb: like> </ div> class='txt-estap'> </ div>
```

It worked perfectly, but it has stopped counting at 1000. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you hit 1000 likes, it only shows a rounded number down to the nearest thousand. So it will stay showing "1000" until you hit 1999 then it will display "2000", and it will stay on that all the way until 2999 likes. Then it will display "3000". Etc...

Comment: Ok, I wonder why (I really do not understand) but I appreciate the attention